# mongodb relations find one with all their related

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I know how to get data with their related

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String
});

var PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    author: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});

...

Post.findOne({_id: id})
    .populate('author')
    .exec(function(error, result) {
        // do stuff    
    })
```

but how to do the opposite?

I mean when I want a user, with all their posts with single query?

Comment: So you want to query a certain user, say with a username value of `foo` and that query should return all their posts?

Comment: yes exactly, find a user with all related posts in one hit

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a filter step after the query returns that manually filters out documents which don't have any posts that matched the populate criteria:

```
var username = "foo";
Post.find()
    .populate('author', null, {username: username})
    .sort({'_id': 1})
    .exec(function (err, posts) {
        posts = posts.filter(function(post){
            return post.author.length;
        });
        res.send(posts);
    });
```

Comment: that is not what I'm looking for, that's two steps, I want to query User with all their posts,I want **one hit**